# Where to get proper AMD drivers?

Tags: drivers

Where can I get proper AMD drivers for my laptop, I download the driver from AMD website manually and via the Auto-Detect program but, it doesn't work, an error appears saying that the program is not compatible with my Windows version while I selected W8.1 while downloading and this is my OS.

I found that Dell no longer provides updates through their support website.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 3521 (i3 version) with AMD Radeon HD 7670M and I use Windows 8.1 N 64-bit.

Comment: how could we guess your hardware if we dont know which model of laptop is, try to edit your question and provide us enough information to give a good answer, we arent magicians.

Comment: It would help to know specific hardware information.  AMD's website is the proper place to get driver updates.  It might be the case, that your GPU is a legacy product, and is driver update are not long issued even by AMD.

Comment: I added the laptop and GPU models @Francisco

Comment: try this http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers/advanced and remember legacy products havent more developement so no more updates for that laptop anymore from AMD site, laptop manufacturer site still providing support but no recent changes

Comment: There website provides an update which shows that it's from 2013 via Windows Device Manager and IOBit Driver Booster 2.

Comment: @AHelmi8x - We need a little mroe information.  Knowing exactly what you downloaded might help.  Knowing if you are running a x64 or x86 version of Windows 8.1 will help.

Comment: @AHelmi8x - You do understand the driver on the Dell website is the last and current driver for your GPU right?  Based on the driver released today, the 7600 series Radeon HD cards have not been supported for awhile now.

Comment: try this driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows+8.1+-+64

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK

Comment: Just FYI, OEM AMD video (chipsets embedded in your system, as opposed to a retail video card you add), have a long reputation of needing the OEM driver from the computer manufacturer rather than the latest driver from the AMD web site.  The latest AMD driver often does not work.  The OEM driver is correct for what is in your system and may not have any updates from the original.  Updates are rarely needed.  It should be downloadable from the Dell web site.

Comment: BTW, if you try a driver from the AMD web site and it doesn't work, and then the OEM driver also doesn't work, it is likely because the AMD driver was not completely removed.  You may need to follow special instructions on the AMD web site or download an uninstaller utility from them.

Answer (score -1):

Win7 32bit [Driver 15.7](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/amd-catalyst-15.7-with-dotnet45-win7-32bit.exe)

Win7 64bit [Driver 15.7](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/amd-catalyst-15.7-with-dotnet45-win7-64bit.exe)

- Try [THIS](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/amd-catalyst-15.7-with-dotnet45-win8.1-64bit.exe) 8.1 driver

Comment: I downloaded this before and It doesn't work.

Comment: @AHelmi8x - Three drivers were offered.  Which one specifically did you try? Are you using a 64-bit operating system or a 32-bit operating system.  You shouldn't even be trying to install a Windows 7 display driver, considering, `Windows Display Driver Model` changed significantly between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Ramhound I use Windows 8.1 64-bit but, I think from the other answers that there will be no new updates for me, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Dell's website is the best bet to find those drivers. You can Google search the model number and usually that will pull a link to the page for that model, and from there you can find the driver you're looking for.

One thing you may want to try as well is updating the driver from device manager. You can usually right click on a driver and have it scan for any updates. This can pull updated drivers pretty easily for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and edit my comment to tell you what happens.